# Indent without adding a bullet point or number in RMarkdown

Tags: r, html-lists, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I want to make an indented list, but I don't want it to have bullet points or numbers. I am using Rmarkdown in RStudio, and knitting to html.

```
#### bla bla bla  

* Example indented line with bullet point  
    * Another indent with another bullet point  
* Yea this is good except for the stupid bullets!  

1. Example indented line with numbers  
    * sure and an indent with a bullet too  
2. But there's these stupid numbers now!  

  two spaces doesn't indent at all  
    or nest indent with 4  
  yea still no indent with 2.  

    four spaces ALSO doesn't indent  
      just makes some stupid code
    why do you hate indents rmd??
```

Comment: "why do you hate indents rmd?" Because Markdown is about _semantics_, not presentation. What do your indents _mean_? Mark them appropriately for the semantics you want and then style them using CSS as Marius shows below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change how a list looks and you're outputting to HTML, use css:

```
---
title: "ListTest"
output: html_document
---

<style>
.nobullet li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
</style>

<div class="nobullet">
* This list
* Doesn't have bullets
</div>

* This list 
* Is normal
```

This won't work for other output formats.

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved using [Line Blocks](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html%23raw-tex#line_blocks) which are built-in to the R Markdown syntax. If you want the indentation to be respected, you can start a line with `|`.

This approach works across multiple output formats and doesn't require any additional CSS styling:

```
---
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

Here is some text with no indentation

|    A list
|         A sublist
|         Sublist Item 2
|         Sublist Item 3
```

Comment: By far, the simplest solution.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work when formating on stackexchange.  Any way to get it working here?

Comment: @Ben this formatting is actually done via Pandoc, as described in the link: "Pandoc understands an extended and slightly revised version of John Gruber’s Markdown syntax. ". It processes the data before presenting the Markdown. So not possible to use this on SE