# How to indent in rmarkdown for word document output?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am writing a code inside a loop that looks like this:

```
for (i in c(1:5)) {

    cat("  ", i,".","**", "Header one","**" , " "  , sep = "\n")
    cat("A)", "Subheader one"  , sep = "\n")
    cat("B)", "Subheader two"  , sep = "\n")
    }
```

I want it to appear in the rendered file as :

```
  Header One  
          A) Subtitle one
          B) Subtitle two
```

how to acheive that?
Edit
This is intended to be exported to word .docx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indent without adding a bullet point or number in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087557/indent-without-adding-a-bullet-point-or-number-in-rmarkdown)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. Use the chunk option `results="asis"`, this tells `knitr` to *write raw results from R into the output document* (which assumes that it is valid in a markdown file) (ref: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results)
2. You don't actually have to force the increasing number for the top-level list, the numbers themselves are ignored by pandoc and converted into a sequential list (ref: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#ordered-lists)
3. If you add too many spaces to the sublists, they may be considered a preformatted code block, so be careful. Namely, 8 is too many, 4 works.

This works:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r chunk1, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
for (i in 1:5) {
  cat("1. Header one",
      "    A) Subheader one",
      "    B) Subheader two",
      sep = "\n")
}
```
````

produces this:

[image: markdown output screenshot]

with this underlying HTML:

```
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>Header one</li>
</ol>
<ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha">
<li>Subheader one</li>
<li>Subheader two</li>
</ol>
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>Header one</li>
</ol>
<ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha">
<li>Subheader one</li>
<li>Subheader two</li>
...
```

Notes:

- I find it confusing to have so many empty strings and such in your example, so I "efficiency'ed" them out. If you have specific formats you want/need, then you can do something like this with `sprintf`:

  ````
  ---
  output: html_document
  ---

  ```{r chunk1, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
  for (i in 1:5) {
    cat(sprintf("1. Header %d", i),
        sprintf("    A) Subheader one - %d", i),
        "    F) Subheader two",
        sep = "\n")
  }
  ```
  ````

  to produce this:

  [image: more markdown output screenshot]
- `c(1:5)` is the same as `1:5`, no `c()` requirement
- multiple calls to `cat` are okay, realizing you need to closely manage the `sep`s between parts of a single call and whatever is needed between calls to `cat` (I prefer one call)

**Edit**

I exported this to Word, too, with:

```
---
output: word_document
---
```

and the sublevels are also indented correctly:

[image: screenshot of word output]

If you see something different, then this could be due to the style in place in the DOCX. This is typically controlled in the reference document, ref: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format#style_reference. I'm using `rmarkdown-1.10` on R-3.5.1, if that differs for you, consider your upgrade options.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am using the spaces because when I export to word it seems that breaks don't work unless I make a space " " . Your solution works great when I export in HTML however when I export to word the subheaders are indented back to be in the same level as header. Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: Looks the same to me, see my edit. Check your versions and (if used) reference docx.